# Why is <input type="button"> submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

```
<form name="callEventForm" method="post" action="/PDC/callevent.do">

     ...

     <input type="button" value="Save" name="addCallEvent" id="addCallEvent" onclick="alert('You clicked me!')"/>

     ...

 </form>
```

When clicking this "Save" button, the form is submitted instead of displaying the alert. I was lead to believe that type="button" would cause the form to not submit on click.

Comment: It doesn't? http://jsfiddle.net/tjRRm/1/

Comment: I wish that was happening on my environment, but it isn't.

Comment: Try: onclick="alert('You clicked me!');return false;".

Comment: Is javascript support enabled? Check this out: http://javascript.about.com/library/blvalsub2.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own questions but this was a weird one. There was an ajax:updateField tag that was overriding the onclick event of the button. Changing the source event of the ajax:updateField allowed my established onclick event to fire appropriately. I know that there's no way anyone would have caught that based on the code I posted, but the rest of the page is so much code that I would hate to make people wade through it.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
onclick="alert('You clicked me!')"
```

To:

```
onclick="alert('You clicked me!');return false;"
```